# Still Getting Dispose(bool)': no suitable method found to override

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am suddenly getting the following error for every form in C# solution, (there are 9 forms):

```
Dispose(bool)': no suitable method found to override
```

I've reviewed the answers to other users' questions about this same error and have confirmed that in my solution all the correct form name exists in both the .cs file and the Designer.cs file.  This happened to all the forms in the solution and I have not renamed any of them in weeks.  Is there any other reason why this might occur?

e.g.

frmXMLGenerator.cs file :

```
namespace XML_Generator
{
    public partial class frmXMLGenerator : Form
    {
```

frmXMLGenerator.Designer.cs file :

```
namespace XML_Generator
{

partial class frmXMLGenerator
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
```

Thanks!

Comment: You haven't shown the entire `Dispose` method declaration. Please show that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Long story short, I am using Entity Framework and just updated my Database Model after creating a few new tables, including a table called 'Form'.  EF generated a Form.cs file and this caused confusion with the Windows.Systems.Forms.Form object for the inheritance declaration.  SMH.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your source files are in different namespaces. The file that was generated by the designer is in the `EFAST_XML_Generator` namespace while your other is in the `XML_Generator` namespace.  They need to match for the partial definition to work.  Either change the one that was not generated or update the namespace in the designer.

Comment: corrected the disconnect with the namespace on all forms, tried to rebuild and am still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same problem, but I got the solution. since I have deleted a form from solution explorer but I don't know how system could not remove form.designer.cs file, that was creating the error. I just deleted that file and error gone.